# Using OLEDB to insert into an Access file from Visual Basic

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio, ms-access, oledb

I've looked through tonnes of tutorials and forums, but STILL can't get this to work. I am creating a windows form application and need to inset a new entry to an access database.

Here's my current code:

```
Dim myConnection As New OleDb.OleDbConnection

    myConnection.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Joe\Documents\ProjectGiggle\ProjectGiggle\Database1.accdb; persist Security Info=False;"

    Dim NewEntrySQLCode As String
    NewEntrySQLCode = ("INSERT Users (UserName, FirstName, SecondName, Password) VALUES ('aUserName2', 'AndAFirstname!', 'PLUSaSecName', 'myPassword');")

Dim NewEntryCmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(NewEntrySQLCode, myConnection)
    NewEntryCmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text
    NewEntryCmd.CommandText = NewEntrySQLCode
    NewEntryCmd.Connection = myConnection

myConnection.Open()
    NewEntryCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    myConnection.Close()
```

The error I get is...

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>   Additional information: Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.

Thanks for your help, much appreciated

Comment: a) The SQL syntax is wrong `INSERT INTO` b) password is a reserved word, escape it with brackets c) the Values list is whacked - you dont really want "aUserName2" used, do you?  Use SQL Paramters d)  Connections, Command and other db provider objects should be wrapped in `Using` blocks to dispose of them e) dont ever store passwords as plaintext - hash them

Comment: You didn't mention what "doesn't work" means, but I imagine it has a lot to do with your insert statement containing five fields but only four values.

Comment: `INTO` is sometimes an optional part of the syntax but I don't remember Access. It does look like the four values for five columns is going to be one problem for sure.

Comment: Thanks all! it was the Password that was messing it up. RE the number of entries, I had actually fic=xed that and simply pasted an old version of code. I feel so silly but thanks for your help!

Comment: @JoeJones Are you saying you got it to work without including `INTO` here ... `INSERT INTO Users`?

Comment: @HansUp I added the INTO after the suggestion, though I saw a MSDN post that didn't use it. Tbh I find you lot much more helpful than MSDN, they expect too much of a dimbo like me!

Comment: I have a fully working code sample here https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Adding-new-records-into-53ce3eb1